# wrap content elements in specific pages differently

Tags: typo3, typoscript

All of my content elements are wrapped using `stdWrap.wrap`.
I am looking for a solution to wrap content elements in the page which i have my `ke_search` added differently .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:

You can conditionally wrap specific content elements using the following typoscript snippet.

```
tt_content { 
       stdWrap { 
          if.value = tx_kesearch_pi2
                  {
                     wrap = | 
                     innerWrap > 
                  } 
         wrap = <div class="someotherclass">|</div>
              } 
         }
```

Comment: that can not be your answer as this is invalid typoscript.

Comment: It was definitely invalid. the answer showed how it works, not a production ready code. i have updated the answer to be valid code (and removed comments and so on)

Comment: it worked absolutely fine for me. it may help some one else too.
No need for deletion

Comment: All of my content elements were wrapped with <div class="someotherclass">|</div> and i wanted to set an exception on tx_kesearch_pi2 content element (I do not wanted to wrap it with anything) and the above snippet worked.
If you have better solution please write it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need another HTML-markup?
Normaly you have another `<div>` around your search results which should enable you to add another styling by CSS.

your page may look like:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
     :
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <div id="C123">
        <h3>my very special CE</h3>
        <p class="bodytext">with some text to demonstrate.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="345">
        <h3>your search results:</h3>
        <div class="search-results">
           <a href="index.php?id=67&s=special">
              <div id="C123">
                 <h3>my very special CE</h3>
                 <p class="bodytext">with some text to demonstrate.</p>
              </div>
           </a>
           <a href="index.php?id=83&s=special">
              <div id="C52">
                 <h2>just a demo</h3>
                 <p class="bodytext">this text is nothing special.</p>
              </div>
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

with appropiate CSS the first CE looks completely different to the same CE in the search results.

```
h3 { color:black; font-size:16px; }
p.bodytext { color:#444; font-size:12px; }

.search-results h3 { color:blue; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; }
.search-results p.bodytext { color:#44b; font-size:10px; font-style:italics; }
```

Comment: i knew that i can solve the problem using css, but so was the requirement. i wanted to have different wrapping on different elements.
I have answered my question